# Где хранить сокеты подключившихся клиентов?

Tags: c++, c, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста, где хранить сокеты подключившихся клиентов ?

Собственно варианта минимум три:

**1)**В статическом массиве или векторе, по типу:

```
std::vector<SOCKET>my_vec_socket;
my_vec_socket.resize(10000);
```

Но в этом случае необходимо или знать точно заранее кол-во максимальных соединений, что маловероятно или выделять память с запасом, но и тут не угадаешь.

**2)**Использовать для хранения std::list - постоянно добавляя в конец сокеты вновь подключившихся клиентов. Тут заранее кол-во подключений знать не надо, но проблема в медленной итерации по листу, что наверное не очень подходит для сервера.

**3)**Можно использовать push_back`и вектора, но так как в какой то момент вызова push_back, внутри вектора вызовется realloc, то надо все операции с сокетами держать под мьютексами, что тоже очень снижает эффективность работы сервера.

И вот может есть еще какие нибудь методы более эффективные ?

Comment: Максимальное количество соединений необходимо знать в любом случае. Итерация по списку не медленная. Нет никакой связи между вызовом realloc и необходимостью в мьютексе.

Comment: @user7860670, а в чем необходимость знать макс. кол-во соединений ? Итерация по списку медленнее, чем по вектору я имел ввиду. Насчет realloc, в момент realloca`а сокеты, которые хранятся в векторе используются другими потоками. Что будет, когда потоки используют элементы вектора по указателю, который будет освобожден и удален ?

Comment: В том, что в полноценных сетевых приложениях необходимо строго следить за количеством ресурсов и ограничивать их потребление. Итерация по списку может быть и несколько медленнее, зато другие операции, прежде всего вставка в конец и удаление из середины куда быстрее. Но не факт, что это будет играть хоть сколько-нибудь значимую роль в производительности сетевого приложения (читайте ограниченного io). ¿Откуда у вас взялись потоки? ¿Одного потока для io не хватает?

Comment: @user7860670, а какой смысл допускать простой потоков ? Готовые задачи из очереди порта завершения - будут доставать столько потоков сколько ядер у процессора. Какой смысл им простаивать ? Проблема в том, как и писал, что к контейнеру в котором будут хранится сокеты будут иметь доступ эти потоки и как то это надо за синхронизировать. Самый простой способ - это мьютексы, но медленно.

Comment: ¿Откуда простой? ¿У вас уже такое мега нагруженное приложение, что для сетевого взаимодействия ему нужно много потоков?

Comment: @user7860670, а что нужно дописывать код по мере увеличения нагрузки ? Под простоем имелось ввиду, что эти потоки просто не будут задействованы. То есть будут простаивать, хотя могли бы были работать.

Comment: Для начала еще нужно дойти до момента, когда перестанет хватать одного потока. И редкое приложение, тем более учебное, доживет до этого момента.

Comment: @user7860670, извините, по-моему это глупость какая то. Зачем куда то доходить не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

*Похоже на преждевременную оптимизацию.*

Даже без переаллокации, у вектора поедет крыша, если его пушбекать без мьютекса. Однако эту проблему можно решить при помощи атомарной переменной и операций типа COMPARE-AND-SWAP - в этом случае, мьютекс будет нужен только в момент переаллокации.

Уже готовая реализация такой стратегии есть в [Facebook/folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly) - я ей пользуюсь и она действительно работает очень быстро.

Comment: Такое может случится, если только пушбекать одновременно из разных потоков.

Comment: @user7860670, имелось ввиду естественно, что сервер многопоточный в любом из случаев, иначе смысл вообще эти сокеты где то сохранять.

Comment: @Optimus1 Хранение сокетов на протяжении времени работы с ними имеет совершенно одинаковый смысл независимо от количества потоков, с ними работающих.